# Github pages still shows README after deploying React app

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I have a `create-react-app` project (https://github.com/khpeek/beomaps/tree/master) which I'd like to deploy to Github pages using [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages). Following this tutorial, https://medium.com/@serverlessguru/deploy-reactjs-app-with-s3-static-hosting-f640cb49d7e6, I've added the following to my `package.json`:

[image]

However, if I run `npm run deploy`, it is published,

[image]

but the Github page, https://khpeek.github.io/beomaps/, still shows default content based on the `README.md`. Do I perhaps need to change the deploy directory?

Comment: It doesn't now. Did you fix it?

Comment: Yep! It turns out you need to select the `gh-pages` branch as your Source in the repository's Options.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the Options page of the repository, I had to select the `gh-pages` branch instead of the `master` branch:

[image]

(I also re-installed `gh-pages` as a normal dependency, not a development one (i.e. `npm install gh-pages --save` instead of `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`), though I'm not sure whether this was important).

Now the page is visible on Github pages:

[image]

Comment: Just adding that in my case I also needed to re-install gh-pages as a production dependency, and that was what did the trick.

Comment: `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` doesn't matters for me

Comment: in my case I only chose that branch and it was resolved. Thanks !

Comment: this worked for me, so +1. One thing to note though -- it takes some time for the change to actually reflect. So may be wait for 15 mins before retrying.

Answer (score 11):

I think this has to do with github not knowing which branch it should use (master vs main or idk). Changing my deploy script as follows solved the issue for me:
`"deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d build"`
This tells github pages that it should use branch main.

Comment: At first after pushing this change and deploying, I got the "404" page on GitHub pages - not even a README! But after a few minutes it resolved to my app. 

Also, I had this problem twice. For the first app I set my branch name to master locally and then pushed the repo. But gh pages really wants your master branch name to be "main". I had to delete the first app because nothing worked to publish it properly.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error even after selecting gh-pages branch, but then I again changed it to master branch and it worked!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it was simply a latency issue. I was able to see the correct page, after few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - when I deployed my React app to GitHub pages, it showed the README.

Then I pushed the build directory I had created locally to my remote repository. When I did that, my React app worked with GitHub pages.

Answer (score 0):

if you with *gh-pages*, you have to select it as defualt branch for this repo. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).