# How to get the drop-down menu for gh pages?

Tags: github-pages

[image]

I follow the online tutorial to deploy me website using react. but my website only show me the Readme.md.

I found that I need to switch the gh pages in setting .
(https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

I have two branch in the repo, but I don't have two choice. (Can anyone tell me how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

In you repo settings, under branches choice, you will see Default branch section, if you have more than one branch, make the ' master ' is your default

Comment: So I change the branch in setting->options is the same as setting->branch? I try this before but it make no difference in the display

Comment: First make the  settings => branch and choose 'master' then for your case, in options => Github Pages => source, choose your master branch that your code on it,

Comment: Master branch is already my default branch and no drop-down menu for me in the options->GitHub pages->source . (https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

Comment: Github pages must be built from the master branch, so if your your 'master' is the default, it should work properly

Comment: but My website only show me the readme.md which is different from my localhost3000. (I try to build a page using react create app)

Comment: see this comment it may be helpful for your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/56400513/5710264

Comment: I rename my repo. (remove the github.io).....then I have the drop down list....

Comment: So, has it worked properly or you have the same problem ?

Comment: I get the idea from what you mention that "Github pages must be built from the master branch" , then I just rename the repo to make it like normal repo but not XXXX.githuh.io . finally, work fine now.