# Only README.md showing on github pages when deploy nextjs app

Tags: javascript, next.js, github-actions, github-pages

I tried to display my Next.js blog on Github pages, but only the README file is displayed. I do not get errors when deploying.
[repolink](https://github.com/Jaserto/mdxblog/)

- The github pages branch in settings is `gh-pages /root`
- I have installed the gh-pages dependencies
- updated next.config.js is below

```js
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '',
  },
  assetPrefix: isProd ? '/mdxblog/' : ''
}
```

- gh-pages.desploy.yml

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages


on:
    push:
    branches: [main]


jobs:
    build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
        run:
        working-directory: ./src

    env:
        NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH: /mdxblog

    strategy:
        matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]


    steps:
        - name: Get files
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
            persist-credentials: false

        - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
            node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        run: npm ci
        run: npm run build
        run: npm run export
        run: touch ./out/.nojekyll

        - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.2.5
        with:
            branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
            folder: out # The folder the action should deploy.
```

Comment: Can u provide Repo link......

Comment: perhaps you can look at this past issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400365/github-pages-still-shows-readme-after-deploying-react-app